# Bifurcation diagram python - no image?

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to make a bifurcation diagram for the following iterated map:
`x_n+1 = x_n * e^(r(1-x_n))`.

First I defined the map:

```
def newmap(x,r):
    return x*math.exp(r*(1-x))
```

Then I tried this:

```
def bifurcation_diagram(rmin=0, rmax=4, r_N=2000, N_min=4000, N = 1000):
    rspace = np.linspace(rmin, rmax, r_N)
    x = 0
    rset = []
    xset = []
    for r in rspace:
        for i in range(N_min + N):
            x = newmap(x,r)
            if i > N_min:
                rset.append(r)
                xset.append(x)
    plt.figure(figsize=(16,7))
    plt.xlim((rmin,rmax))
    plt.ylim((0,5))
    plt.scatter(rset,xset,s=0.3,c='C0',linewidth=0)
    plt.xlabel(r'r', fontsize=20)
    plt.ylabel(r'$x_{end}$', fontsize=29, rotation=0)
    plt.show()
```

When I try `bifurcation_diagram()` I get a blank plot.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: What's `newmap`?

Comment: whoops, it's the function for the map I gave at the start. I 'll edit it in.

Comment: Have you looked to see if `rset` and `xset` contains the values that you think they should contain?

Comment: For any choice of `r` you have `newmap(0,r) == 0`, so I don't know what you are expecting to see. Perhaps the fix is as simple as initializing the iteration seed to be something other than the fixed point `x=0`

Comment: Yeah I missed that completely. I've tried again with different initial values of x but they all seem to give a horizontal line at x_{end} = 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `x=0` is a fixed point and so is `x=1`. If you switch `x=0` to `x=0.1` but otherwise leave it where it is, the first `r` value drives `x` to (what is for those values) the attracting fixed point `1`. You need to put `x=0.1` *inside* of the main loop:

```
for r in rspace:
    x = 0.01
```

(with everything else as before).